# crear multiplicacion de matrices en lenguaje c

Tags: c

Tengo un pequeño problema me he creado un programa para calcular la suma resta y multiplicación de 2 matrices con orden definido por el usuario, ya he creado la suma y la resta pero la multiplicación no la he podido desarrollar, me he creado un if en donde verifica si la matriz es compatible, pero al momento de querer desarrollarlo no me da los resultados esperados.

Les adjunto el código que he desarrollado esperando me puedan asisitir, de antemano agradezco mucho su apoyo. (cabe destacar que el codigo aqui citado esta dentro del main)

```
int matriz1[100][100], matriz2[100][100], filas1, columnas1, filas2, columnas2;
int  matrizRes[100][100];
int i, j, k , l, opcion, suma, temporal;

//--------------------------------------------------- Matriz 1
printf("Filas Matriz 1: ");
scanf("%d", &filas1);
printf("Columnas Matriz 1: ");
scanf("%d", &columnas1);

//------------------------------Llenar la matriz
for(i=0; i<filas1; i++) //Filas
{
    for(j=0; j<columnas1; j++)//Columnas
    {
        printf("Introduzca un numero en la posicion [%d][%d]: ", i ,j);
        scanf("%d", &matriz1[i][j]);
    }//Fin Columnas
}//Fin Filas
printf("\n");

//-----------------------------Mostrar la matriz
for(i=0; i<filas1; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<columnas1; j++)
    {
        printf("[%d]", matriz1[i][j]);
    }// Fin columnas
    printf("\n");
}//Fin filas

//--------------------------------------------------- Matriz 2
printf("\nFilas Matriz 2: ");
scanf("%d", &filas2);
printf("Columnas Matri2 1: ");
scanf("%d", &columnas2);

//------------------------------Llenar la matriz
for(i=0; i<filas2; i++) //Filas
{
    for(j=0; j<columnas2; j++)//Columnas
    {
        printf("Introduzca un numero en la posicion [%d][%d]: ", i,j);
        scanf("%d", &matriz2[i][j]);
    }//Fin Columnas
}//Fin Filas

printf("\n");
//-----------------------------Mostrar la matriz
for(i=0; i<filas2; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<columnas2; j++)
    {
        printf("[%d]", matriz2[i][j]);
    }// Fin columnas
    printf("\n");
}//Fin filas

getche();
system("cls");

//---------------------------------------------------Menu de Opciones
do
{
    printf("---------- MENU DE OPCIONES ----------");
    printf("\n1.- Mostrar Matrices");
    printf("\n2.- Suma de Matrices");
    printf("\n3.- Resta de Matrices");
    printf("\n4.- Multiplicacion de Matrices");
    printf("\n5.- Salir");
    printf("\n\nOpcion: ");
    scanf("%d", &opcion);

    switch(opcion)
    {
        case 1: //Mostrar Matrices
            system("cls");
            //Matriz 1
            printf("Matriz 1\n");
            for(i=0; i<filas1; i++)
            {
                for(j=0; j<columnas1; j++)
                {
                    printf("[%d]", matriz1[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");   
            }
            printf("\n");

            //Matriz 2
            printf("Matriz 2\n");
            for(i=0; i<filas2; i++)
            {
                for(j=0; j<columnas2; j++)
                {
                    printf("[%d]", matriz2[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            getche();
            system("cls");
        break; // Fin case 1

        case 2: //Suma de Matrices
            system("cls");
            //Matriz Resultante
            printf("Suma de Matrices\n");
            if (filas1 != filas2 || columnas1 != columnas2)
            {
                printf("\nNo se puede realizar la suma de matrices ya que no son de las mismas dimensiones");
            }
            else
            {
                //Se realiza la suma de las matrices
                for(i=0; i<filas1; i++)
                {
                    for(j=0; j<columnas1; j++)
                    {
                        matrizRes[i][j] = matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j];
                    }
                }//Fin suma

                //Se muestra la matriz resultante
                for(i=0; i<filas1; i++)
                {
                    for(j=0; j<columnas1; j++)
                    {
                        printf("[%d]", matrizRes[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }//Fin suma
            }//else suma

            getche();
            system("cls");
        break;

        case 3:
            //Matriz Resultante
            printf("Resta de Matrices\n");
            if (filas1 != filas2 || columnas1 != columnas2)
            {
                printf("\nNo se puede realizar la suma de matrices ya que no son de las mismas dimensiones");
            }
            else
            {
                //Se realiza la suma de las matrices
                for(i=0; i<filas1; i++)
                {
                    for(j=0; j<columnas1; j++)
                    {
                        matrizRes[i][j] = matriz1[i][j] - matriz2[i][j];
                    }
                }//Fin suma

                //Se muestra la matriz resultante
                for(i=0; i<filas1; i++)
                {
                    for(j=0; j<columnas1; j++)
                    {
                        printf("[%d]", matrizRes[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }//Fin suma
            }//else suma

            getche();
            system("cls");
        break;

        case 4:
            system("cls");
            //Matriz Resultante
            printf("Multiplicacion de Matrices\n");
            if(columnas1 != filas2)
            {
                printf("\nNo se puede realizar la multiplicacion ya que son matrices incompatibles");
            }
            else
            {

            }//fin hacer la multiplicacion



                for(i=0; i<filas1; i++)
                {
                    for(j=0; j<columnas2; j++)
                    {
                        printf("[%d]", matrizRes[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }//Fin suma

            }//fin else multiplicacion

            getche();
            system("cls");
        break;  


    }//Fin de Switch Case
}while(opcion!=5);//Fin do-while switch-case

getche();
return 0;
```

Comment: En ningun momento estas haciendo la multiplicacion, puede ser por eso?

Comment: Has compartido más de doscientas líneas. Por favor, comparte sólo la parte relevante para tu pregunta.

Comment: De hecho lo intente de varias maneras pero no me permite hacer la multiplicación esperaba que alguien me pudiese iluminar o ayudando resolviendo esa parte del problema

Answer (score 2):

Centrándome solo en la lógica, para multiplicar dos matrices compatibles, `matriz1` y `matriz2`, se debe considerar:

1. La fila `i` de `matriz1` se multiplica por la columna `j` de `matriz2` para obtener el elemento `(i,j)` de la matriz resultado.
2. Esta multiplicación se hace elemento a elemento, como las matrices son compatibles entonces el número de elementos de la fila `i` de `matriz1` es igual al número de elementos de la columna `j` de `matriz2`, por lo que cada elemento de la fila de `matriz1` tiene su correspondiente elemento en la columna de `matriz2`, estos elementos se multiplican y se acumulan.

Este sería el código que realiza la multiplicación, considerando que las variables `i`, `j`, `k` y `suma`, ya fueron declaradas en tu código.

```
        for (i = 0; i < filas1; i++) {//se itera através de cada fila de matriz1
            for (j = 0; j < columnas2; j++) {//se itera através de cada columna de matriz2
                suma = 0;//es donde se almacenará el valor final 
                for (k = 0; k < columnas1; k++) {
                    suma += matriz1[i][k] * matriz2[k][j];//se acumula en suma
                }
                matrizRes[i][j] = suma;
            }
        }
```